Bug? Relationship lost when merging if both contacts have the same relationship with the same contact
I recreated this on the sandbox site:

Edit the employee relationship on the contact "Alabama Action Fund". Add a relationship start date (like a year ago) and an end date (like a month ago).

Create a new organization with the same name and add an employee relationship to the same individual. Give the relationship a start date of 2 weeks ago... no end date.

Merge the 2 organization contacts, newer one > older one (default). Notice that merging the relationships is checked.

The resulting organization only shows one of the 2 relationships and has lost the newer (active) one.


I think I have seen this behavior for a long time and should have posted it earlier.
